# Node.js Installation test is not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-gyp

I have installed Node.js using snap command:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=11
```

It has installed successfully. Here is the output.

```
muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_react$ node -v
v11.14.0
muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_react$ npm -v
6.7.0
```

But when I try to test the installation using the command:

```
muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_react$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/test | bash -
```

it outputs correctly but ends up with few error:

```
muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_react$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/test | bash -

## Testing Node.js and npm installation ...

+ mkdir _test-node-install && cd _test-node-install

## Creating test package ...


## Installing dependencies ...

+ npm install --spin=false --loglevel=info --cache=.npm-test-cache
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.7.0
npm info using node@v11.14.0
npm info lifecycle test@1.0.0~preinstall: test@1.0.0
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hyperquest 1195ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools 1200ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl 1228ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/through 281ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer 285ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl/-/bl-0.9.5.tgz 272ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.2.7.tgz 257ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer/-/duplexer-0.1.1.tgz 263ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 534ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.0.34.tgz 266ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder 269ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is 286ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray 286ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.31.tgz 261ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 741ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 3124ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 3133ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 7ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hyperquest/-/hyperquest-0.3.0.tgz 273ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools/-/buffertools-2.1.6.tgz 276ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.2.tgz 280ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz 707ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.3.tgz 749ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 817ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 12ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 34ms
npm info lifecycle core-util-is@1.0.2~preinstall: core-util-is@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle duplexer@0.1.1~preinstall: duplexer@0.1.1
npm info lifecycle inherits@2.0.3~preinstall: inherits@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle isarray@0.0.1~preinstall: isarray@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle string_decoder@0.10.31~preinstall: string_decoder@0.10.31
npm info lifecycle readable-stream@1.0.34~preinstall: readable-stream@1.0.34
npm info lifecycle through@2.2.7~preinstall: through@2.2.7
npm info lifecycle bl@0.9.5~preinstall: bl@0.9.5
npm info lifecycle buffertools@2.1.6~preinstall: buffertools@2.1.6
npm info lifecycle hyperquest@0.3.0~preinstall: hyperquest@0.3.0
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 4ms
npm info linkStuff core-util-is@1.0.2
npm info linkStuff duplexer@0.1.1
npm info linkStuff inherits@2.0.3
npm info linkStuff isarray@0.0.1
npm info linkStuff string_decoder@0.10.31
npm info linkStuff readable-stream@1.0.34
npm info linkStuff through@2.2.7
npm info linkStuff bl@0.9.5
npm info linkStuff buffertools@2.1.6
npm info linkStuff hyperquest@0.3.0
npm timing action:build Completed in 5ms
npm info lifecycle core-util-is@1.0.2~install: core-util-is@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle duplexer@0.1.1~install: duplexer@0.1.1
npm info lifecycle inherits@2.0.3~install: inherits@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle isarray@0.0.1~install: isarray@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle string_decoder@0.10.31~install: string_decoder@0.10.31
npm info lifecycle readable-stream@1.0.34~install: readable-stream@1.0.34
npm info lifecycle through@2.2.7~install: through@2.2.7
npm info lifecycle bl@0.9.5~install: bl@0.9.5
npm info lifecycle buffertools@2.1.6~install: buffertools@2.1.6
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/1935/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> buffertools@2.1.6 install /home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install/node_modules/buffertools
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.14.0 | linux | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.14.0/node-v11.14.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.14.0/node-v11.14.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/snap/node/1935/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install/node_modules/buffertools/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/snap/node/1935/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/snap/node/1935/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install/node_modules/buffertools',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install/node_modules/buffertools/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/buffertools/buffertools.o
../buffertools.cc: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::FillAction::apply(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&, uint32_t)’:
../buffertools.cc:256:44: warning: ‘int32_t v8::Value::Int32Value() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       int c = args[args_start]->Int32Value();
                                            ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2572:46: note: declared here
   V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", int32_t Int32Value() const);
                                              ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:261:43: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       String::Utf8Value s(args[args_start]);
                                           ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2992:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:266:56: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Local<Object> other = args[args_start]->ToObject();
                                                        ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::IndexOfAction::apply(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const uint8_t*, size_t, const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&, uint32_t)’:
../buffertools.cc:329:54: warning: ‘int32_t v8::Value::Int32Value() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     int32_t start = args[args_start + 1]->Int32Value();
                                                      ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2572:46: note: declared here
   V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", int32_t Int32Value() const);
                                              ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc: In function ‘void {anonymous}::Concat(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
../buffertools.cc:449:29: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       size += arg->ToString()->Utf8Length();
                             ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10251:15: note: declared here
 Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc:449:43: warning: ‘int v8::String::Utf8Length() const’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       size += arg->ToString()->Utf8Length();
                                           ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2682:52: note: declared here
   V8_DEPRECATED("Use Isolate version instead", int Utf8Length() const);
                                                    ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:452:50: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       size += node::Buffer::Length(arg->ToObject());
                                                  ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc:470:30: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       String::Utf8Value v(arg);
                              ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2992:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:475:39: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Local<Object> b = arg->ToObject();
                                       ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::UnaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::ClearAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:431:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:141:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::BinaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::CompareAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:432:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:169:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc:177:43: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       String::Utf8Value s(args[args_start]);
                                           ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2992:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:187:55: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Local<Object> other = args[args_start]->ToObject();
                                                       ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::BinaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::EqualsAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:433:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:169:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc:177:43: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       String::Utf8Value s(args[args_start]);
                                           ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2992:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:187:55: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Local<Object> other = args[args_start]->ToObject();
                                                       ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::UnaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::FillAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:434:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:141:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::UnaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::FromHexAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:435:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:141:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::BinaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::IndexOfAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:436:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:169:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc:177:43: warning: ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use Isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       String::Utf8Value s(args[args_start]);
                                           ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:2992:28: note: declared here
                   explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj));
                            ^
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../buffertools.cc:187:55: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Local<Object> other = args[args_start]->ToObject();
                                                       ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::UnaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::ReverseAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:437:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:141:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
../buffertools.cc: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> {anonymous}::UnaryAction<Derived>::operator()(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) [with Derived = {anonymous}::ToHexAction]’:
../buffertools.cc:438:1:   required from here
../buffertools.cc:141:33: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       target = args[0]->ToObject();
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../buffertools.cc:17:
/home/muhammad/.node-gyp/11.14.0/include/node/v8.h:10257:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/buffertools.node
  COPY Release/buffertools.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install/node_modules/buffertools/build'
gyp info ok 
npm timing audit submit Completed in 1220ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 1219ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 1ms
npm info lifecycle hyperquest@0.3.0~install: hyperquest@0.3.0
npm timing action:install Completed in 9680ms
npm info lifecycle core-util-is@1.0.2~postinstall: core-util-is@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle duplexer@0.1.1~postinstall: duplexer@0.1.1
npm info lifecycle inherits@2.0.3~postinstall: inherits@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle isarray@0.0.1~postinstall: isarray@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle string_decoder@0.10.31~postinstall: string_decoder@0.10.31
npm info lifecycle readable-stream@1.0.34~postinstall: readable-stream@1.0.34
npm info lifecycle through@2.2.7~postinstall: through@2.2.7
npm info lifecycle bl@0.9.5~postinstall: bl@0.9.5
npm info lifecycle buffertools@2.1.6~postinstall: buffertools@2.1.6
npm info lifecycle hyperquest@0.3.0~postinstall: hyperquest@0.3.0
npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 4ms
npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 10583ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
npm info linkStuff test@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@1.0.0~install: test@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@1.0.0~postinstall: test@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@1.0.0~prepublish: test@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle test@1.0.0~prepare: test@1.0.0
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 13780ms
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No license field.

added 10 packages from 12 contributors and audited 10 packages in 13.894s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm timing npm Completed in 14362ms
npm info ok 

## Running test ...

+ npm test
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/1935/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> test@1.0.0 test /home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install
> npm start; node test.js

npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/1935/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> test@1.0.0 start /home/muhammad/workspace_react/_test-node-install
> node server.js &

(node:30416) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 4294967296000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timer duration was truncated to 2147483647.
SUCCESS
(node:30416) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

## Cleaning up ...

+ rm -rf _test-node-install
muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_react$
```

Is there anything wrong in my installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not errors, those are warnings. Everything should be fine.

Comment: But when I try to install a create project I end up with some other problem related to permission.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsin That's unrelated to this. If you're using `-g` to install you have to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. But using sudo is not recommended anywhere. :)

Comment: @MuhammadMohsin Can you please accept my answer then? :)

Comment: No problem I just accepted since you are saying these are warning and I should nothing to worry about so based on your credible answer I marked it accepted.